# Sites search should suppress our top 5 in the "... More Sites" view

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

In the left most / lower pane showing your network profile and down to log out contains a site browser.

It lets you choose and order sites you may be interested (awesome!)

[image]

When you tap More Sites, the list wastes space on sites you already follow. Please suppress those sites from the secondary list to make better use of the screen area. (Why would I go to a sub menu and scroll past sites I already have pinned?)

[image]

Also, make an equivalent filter on the Add site function called by tapping edit (labeled *Filter here as well**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partially addressed in 0.1.25 and will be completely addressed in 0.1.26.  For things like adding a pinned site or voting to migrate, the sites that won't be there will be excluded from both the default and search views.  For "More Sites", the sites in your menu will be excluded from the default view but appear when searching.  That way you can always find any site from that screen.